# React Native - redux state updates but tabbar does not

Tags: react-native, redux, navigation, tabbar, darkmode

I try to implement dark mode for my app.
I use redux state management to save my current theme.

I use the redux connect function in my components to get this theme and render the components in light or dark mode.
This works pretty good but unfortunately I have problems with my BottomTabbar.

I use a functional custom tabbar component, where I get the current redux state.
I also tried to connect my AnimatedCircleBarComponent itself to redux state  (so connecting it with my class component) but the result was the same.

```
const MaterialTopTabBar = props => {
 const Colors = useSelector(state => state.themeReducer.theme);

 return (
   <AnimatedCircleBarComponent
     {...props}
     style={{
       backgroundColor: Colors.tabbar,
     }}
     activeTintColor={Colors.icon}
     inactiveTintColor={Colors.icon}
     fillColor={Colors.tabbar}
     activeBackgroundColor={Colors.iconActive}
     // indicatorStyle={styles.indicatorStyle}
     // style={styles.root}
   />
 );
};
```

Here's my Navigator:

```
const MainTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({screenProps}) => {
        return {
          tabBarLabel: () => <Text></Text>,
          tabBarIcon: ({tintColor, focused}) => (
            <Icon
              size={28}
              name={focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'}
              style={
                focused
                  ? {color: screenProps.Colors.textWhite}
                  : {color: screenProps.Colors.icon, top: 6}
              }
            />
          ),
        };
      },
    },

    Restaurants: {
      screen: RestaurantScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({screenProps}) => {
        return {
          tabBarLabel: () => <Text></Text>,
          tabBarIcon: ({tintColor, focused}) => (
            <Icon
              size={28}
              name={focused ? 'format-list-checkbox' : 'format-list-checkbox'}
              style={
                focused
                  ? {color: screenProps.Colors.textWhite}
                  : {color: screenProps.Colors.icon, top: 6}
              }
            />
          ),
        };
      },
    },
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: MaterialTopTabBar,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    optimizationsEnabled: true,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  },
);
```

The tabbar component does receive the new state but it does not rerender itself.
It only rerenders and changes the colors to the new ones after pressing on a new tab.

Is it possible to force rerendering of the tabbar or why does this not work?
All other components in my screen itself are updating correctly.

I think this is a pretty common usecase, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
The coding above works like a charm, my problem was my Custom tab bar component.

It has a "ShouldComponentUpdate" method which denied the update. I adjusted this method and now it works.

Hope I can help somebody with this information.